# SOLUCION TEMPORAL mayo 2022 error build ios xcode 13.3.1 mac con intel o M1

Tags: flutter, ios, vscode, xcode

Solución temporal mayo 2022 error build ios xcode 13.3.1 mac con intel o M1

A muchos puede darle este error dias me a costado a prueba y error pero tengo la solución a este error que es un error en general a las macs que an actualizado a SO Monterey(intel y M1) y xcode 13.3.1

el error es el siguiente:

2022-03-15 23:23:28.852 xcodebuild[72218:2172565] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

```
2022-03-15 23:23:28.852 xcodebuild[72218:2172565] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido! Gracias por compartir tu hallazgo! Trata de plasmarlo como una pregunta y su respuesta, de forma que otros puedan encontrarlo fácilmente en el futuro. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: la solución que encontre fue hacer un downgrade al sdk de flutter pero no cualquier ver. si no la ver. Flutter ->2.10.0 Dart ->2.16.0



la cual se puede descargar aqui:

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos



una vez descargada seguimos con agregar en el path la carpeta de flutter 

validamos que se tomen los cambios con flutter --version y ya podemos hacer el proyecto desde 0

Comment: Recuerda que el formato de [es.so] es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Esto es: pon _la pregunta_ como pregunta, y _la respuesta_ (o solución) como respuesta. Cuando agregues tu respuesta, [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Lo que colocaste como comentario, debe ir _como respuesta_.